# Node.js express does not print anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket

So I moved app.listen to the top, but now it gives me an error that port is in use. I believe this is because I set up my websocket on this port, but how do I do it then?

```
var server = require('websocket').server, http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.listen(8080);

var socket = new server({
    httpServer: http.createServer().listen(8080)
});


socket.on('request', function(request) {
    var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);

    app.get('/', function(request, response) {
        var id = request.query.steamid;
        console.log("STEAMID:",id);
        response.send("I have received the ID: " + id);
    });

    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        connection.sendUTF(message);
    });

    connection.on('close', function(connection) {
        console.log('connection closed');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to listen on `connection` and not on `request`

```
socket.on('connection', function(sock) {       
    sock.on('message', function(message) {
        sock.send(message);
    });

    sock.on('close', function() {
        console.log('connection closed');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @VickyGonsalves for responding, I've edited my topic a little.

Answer (score 0):

put your `app.listen(3000);`  outside of request event.
so,your express server get chance to initialize port to listen.

Currently it is in callback of `request event`  and it will get called once client-server connection of web-socket is established.

As far as URL concern

```
ws://localhost:8080/?steamid=123456789
```

you have  configured websocket to listen on port 8080.But your express is configured to listen port 3000.So it is not possible to catch request on express Server configured on different port which is requested through web-socket configured on another different port.

url should be like this.

```
http://localhost:3000/?steamid=123456789
```

because your express server using `http protocol and not websocket`

Comment: Please look at my code above. So it only parses variables in http? How do I parse them in javascript websocket then?

Comment: U r using same port for both express and websocket.Please use different

Comment: but if client connects to server with port 8080, and I set express to port 3000, will it still work?

Comment: Depend on clients protocol and port